# Using JQuery to create CSS styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Often when I'm making websites I get incredibly frustrated trying to do certain things with CSS and find it much easier to use JQuery to add CSS styles.

For example, trying to vertically align divs is a nightmare in CSS so I normally use JQuery to find the height of the parent and add the relevant top margin on the child.

My question to all you intelligent, experienced coders (unlike myself) is... Is this bad practice? Do I need to go through the pains of CSS positioning or can I simply continue using JQuery to add certain styles?

Comment: If possible, use `CSS` if not then you should use `$.css()`

Comment: you can do it that way, but you are the first person i have ever heard of, who sais, CSS is harder than JS :D what are your problems with css? it's nearly "normal" HTML

Comment: Similar to you before 2-3 years ago I was also using `jquery` for certain things.
But always try to solve certain things by `CSS` if it it's not possible then only use `javascript` or `jquery`.

Comment: I think each thing has its own function. So, if you can do it with css and it is a css thing (and it is) you should do it with css. By this way you manage your css things in your css file, leaving the js for the real javascript needs.

Comment: Using JavaScript as a crutch for the UI is an incredibly bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

If it is doable with CSS only, it's usually a better practice:

- it respects **the separation of concerns** (CSS should be the one responsible for the visuals), it will usually be more maintainable for the same reason (you'll know that you have to look into css code, when something doesn't look right)
- those solutions **will be faster** whan most of what you can achieve with JavaScript
- in most cases it will also be more bulletproof solution. I found that if I'm trying to do something "clever" with JavaScript and layouts, I often forget some weird conditions and bugs that appears in results are really nasty.

Also, in general, think of it this way: CSS is one of the main layers of your web application. One way or another, you will have to know what's going on there (and it would be optimal to also know *why*), so the more fluent with CSS you'll become the better.

I really recommend https://css-tricks.com/ for any level of CSS apprentice (*I revisit their [Guide To Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) every several days:D*)

Answer (score 0):

The most important practice is to get your job done in a way where it will clear what you did and why you did it. The vertical centering problem is a good example. It is possible to get it done today in a way that it wasn't possible before, or in any case in a less complicated way. So if you are in a position where you have enough time to hack away on a perfect solution, fine. The reality is that, not only are there deadlines, but sometimes you are not paid for this and the client doesn't care. You can try to get him to care, but if you can't, you need to make a trade off. In reality, there are rarely perfect solutions anyway.

So as a practical example, I'd say good practice in this case would be to use a simple and effective solution like [this](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/), and then use something like Modernizr to apply the least time consuming solution (i.e. your own) as  fallback for the minority of old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can say it's bad practice because jQuery(.css()) will take more time then you have done by using only css styles

so as i have learned i will say that 
do the work with given priority to solve the Problem i think that would be

**try to solve with HTML >>> ( if not solved ) try to solve with CSS  >>> ( still not solved ) go with jQuery**

this is what i thought